# I do not get a response after a post JavaScript CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, codeigniter

I have a dropdown with courses names(like 'php', 'c', 'c#' ... ).
I also have an onchange event put on it so that I can check if the option from the drop-down is valid(is found in my database) - *it may seem stupid, as I myself I am puting those values in the dropdown from my database, but I am doing it for protecting against SQL injection*.

The problem is I do not receive a response from **verifycourse.php** ... so it is something there that I do wrong.

**function.js**

```
function complete() {
    $.post("verifycourse/domain", {
        domain: $('#domain').val().toLowerCase()
    }).done(function (returnValue) {
        alert('after post'); //it does not alert
        var result = jQuery.parseJSON(returnValue);
        if (result['returnValue'] == 'ok') {
            alert('good domain');
        }
        else if (result['returnValue'] == 'wrong') {
            alert('wrong domain');
        }
    });
}
```

**verifycourse.php**

```
function index($param = 1)
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('user','',TRUE);
    $this->load->library( 'mysmarty' ); 
    $smarty = new Mysmarty ;

    if (isset($param) && $param == 'domain') {
        $this->isValidCourse($this->input->post('domain'));
    }
  }

    function isValidCourse($courseName)
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('admins');

        $arr = $this->user->getDomains($courseName);
        if(in_array($courseName, $arr))
            return json_encode(array('returnValue' => 'ok'));
        return json_encode(array('returnValue' => 'wrong'));
    }
```

**user.php**

```
function getDomains()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('admins');

        $arr = array();
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            if ($row->subject && !(in_array($row->subject, $arr)))
                $arr[] = $row->subject;
        }

        return $arr;
    }
```

**home_view.tpl**

```
<div class="modal-body">
                <form class="contact" name="contact">
                    <font color="red"><div id="errors"></div></font>
                    <input type="text" class="input-block-level" id="courseName" placeholder="Course name" name="courseName"/>
                    <br/>
                    <select class="input-block-level" id="domain" placeholder="Domain name" name="domain" onchange="complete();">
                      {foreach from=$myArray item=foo}
                          <option value="foo">{$foo}</option>
                      {/foreach}
                    </select>       
                </form>
            </div>
```

Comment: error or typo? `f(in_aray($courseName, $arr))` should be `in_array`

Comment: can't believe... error, but still does not alert

Comment: do you not get any alerts? not ever `alert("after post")`?

Comment: not even that one...

Comment: doesnt this `$smarty = new Mysmarty;` need to be this `$smarty = new Mysmarty();`?

Comment: Nop, all my others function and features work perfectly good.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `$.post` to `$.ajax` in order to catch other errors, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "verifycourse/domain",
    data: {domain: $('#domain').val().toLowerCase()},
    success: function(msg){
        alert(  msg );
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, error) {
        alert("some error");
        console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(error);
   }
});
```

Comment: I did and it alerts "some error"...how is this helping me to find out what is that  I do wrong?

Comment: check your console. do you know how to do that?

Comment: yea, it is full of 404 errors and I get some even at  console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(error); ... Uncaught ReferenceError: error is not defined

Comment: that means that its not reaching the controller at all. I think the problem is that you are using this URL: `"verifycourse/domain"` , but you need to use `"verifycourse/index"` and in your `index()` method, you need to catch the posted variables with `$this->input->post()`

Comment: Or you can also change the URL to `verifycourse/index/domain`

Comment: I have changed the url to verifycourse/index/domain

I get the same 'some problem' alert

Comment: do you have Teamviewer? maybe i can help you remotely

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80994/discussion-between-lulu-and-codegodie).

Answer (score 0):

```
function complete() {
        $.post("verifycourse/domain", {
            domain: $('#domain').val().toLowerCase()
        },function (returnValue) {
            alert('after post'); //it does not alert
            var result = jQuery.parseJSON(returnValue);
            if (result['returnValue'] == 'ok') {
                alert('good domain');
            }
            else if (result['returnValue'] == 'wrong') {
                alert('wrong domain');
            }
        });
    }
```